# How to show Toast on homescreen

Tags: android, kotlin, toast, android-toast, onpause

I have an activity that uses:

```
val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
    startActivity(i)

Toast.makeText(this, "Fetching attendance, hold your phone close to the terminal ...", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

To automatically return to the home screen once the function above is called, but the toast does not show up. How can I make a toast show up while on the home screen?

Comment: Can you post your full activity code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` stands for the context. So instead of using `this` use `applicationContext`

```
Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Fetching attendance, hold your phone close to the terminal ...", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```